# How often should an ecommerce site break?

Tags: web-development

I've been working with some ecommerce sites for 3 years+ and throughout they have required between 10 and 40 hours developer work per month to stay running, each. They are 10+ years old, run on Magento, and SQL. They typically have about 50 users/day at peak.

How does my experience compare to others' expectations? I am keeping in mind that direct equivalence it not possible with so little information.

Comment: Personally, in three years use I would expect **ZERO** failures.  I would not accept an SLA of less than 99.999% uptime.  But I expect that this question is subject to individual opinion.

Comment: Without knowing more information it is hard to say.  If the ecommerce site deals with a bunch of different data feeds (apis) then yes it very well could take 10 to 40 hours a month. But a standard ecommerce store where you add products in the admin area and sell them should require very little maintenance to keep it running.

Comment: Anything that old is likely to require some type of routine maintenance, even if it's just keeping an eye on the database and running a bit of optimization. Also, if the site is not on a managed host, just keeping the CMS and its modules up to date may require 10+ hours to perform the updates and then do some regression testing to make sure the updates didn't break anything.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. There is no SLA at all from the agency, work is charged hourly. There aren't a bunch of data feeds; in fact, one of the sites is a brochure site. Some updates do go on routinely, but the vast majority of developer time is spent repairing features that spontaneously break.

Comment: What kind of features spontaneously break?  In my experience only third party integrations do that.   I've found Facebook and Google login to be very fragile.  Sometimes payment processors need to be updated.

Comment: Features such as pagination, the shop filter, or site search to name recent examples.